# How to pass form element values to the ajax success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm submitting a number of dynamic forms via ajax using this code:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'data/process.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(), // <----"this" is current form context
        success: function () {
            gaddress();
        },
        error: function (xhr) { //<----error function

            gerroraddress(xhr);

        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The code works well but the issue is that I want to be able to provide dynamic response like below:

```
function gaddress(form) {
    if (form = "addressform") {
        var msg = "Address form updated successfully.";
        jQuery.jGrowl(msg, {
            life: 10000,
            position: 'center'
        });
        vaddress();
    }
}
```

That way, I will provide appropriate response and redirect after successful form submit based on the form submitted.

How do I get the form name being submitted or the name of one of the form elements so I can pass it as a parameter to my success function: `gaddress()` ?

Also, I need to show a loading bar when form is processing and exit the loading bar after successful completion.

Comment: mind posting the form html?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
var form = $(this).attr("id"); //Or any attribute here
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'data/process.php',
  data: $(this).serialize(), // <----"this" is current form context
  success: function () {
     gaddress(form);
  },
  error: function (xhr) { //<----error function

      gerroraddress(xhr);

  }
});
```

Comment: var form is coming as undefined when passed to success function: gaddress() Any help?

Comment: I think your form does not have id

Comment: Sorry, but the form does have id and name: eaddressform $(this).name also returned undefined. Any help please?